# Multi user connect and do CRUD simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I'm using ASP.NET Framework 4, IIS 7 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have got an error like:
`{column} not found in selected DataSource,
SQL Reader is close`, ....

It only happens when:

1. Multiple users are connected.
2. They make CRUD (Create, Retrive, Update, Delete) calls simultaneously.

Strangely, it escape my catch:

```
try{
    Connexion_D.GetConnected();
    // doing CRUD
}
catch{
    // catching Error, avoid yellow page aspx
}
finally
{
    Connexion_D.CloseConnection();
}
```

And my connection class:

```
public class Connexion_D
{

    static public SqlConnection conn;
    static public SqlConnection GetConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            String strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxxx"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception excThrown)
        {
            conn = null;
            throw new Exception(excThrown.InnerException.Message, excThrown);
        }

        // Ouverture et restitution de la connexion en cours
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
    static public Boolean IsConnected
    {
        get { return (conn != null) && (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) && (conn.State != ConnectionState.Broken); }
    }

    static public void CloseConnection()
    {
        // Libération de la connexion si elle existe
        if (IsConnected) conn.Close();
    }
}
```

So I don't think the code is wrong / has a bug.

I think it may be the configuration of IIS and SQL server.

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please include full details of the error and sample code that will demonstrate the error, ie. enough information to re-create. Also read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for further hints on making this an answerable question.

Comment: A field or property with name 'XXX' was not found in the selected data source. but like i said it only happen when multi user, coz i checked that this xxx Exist and i have no probleme when i connected alone.

Comment: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. Connection is currently closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, then this looks very dubious:

```
static public SqlConnection conn;     
static public SqlConnection GetConnected() {         
    try         
    {             
        String strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxxx"].ConnectionString;             
        conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    } 
}

static public void CloseConnection() {           
    // Libération de la connexion si elle existe           
    if (IsConnected) conn.Close();       
}
```

You're working with a static connection variable, which means that when you close it, you're closing the last one that was opened.

In a multi-user scenario, you could be having this happen:

- User A: Create connection (and return connection 1)
- User A: Execute query (runs against connection 1)
- User B: Create connection (and return connection 2)
- User A: Close connection (last one opened was 2, so that's closed)
- User B: Execute query (runs against connection 2, it's already been closed... bang)

As an aside, you should probably reconsider having your connection as a public member variable:

```
static public SqlConnection conn;
```

This is generally considered bad practice and can lead to unexpected / hard to track down errors in the future if any code outside of your class starts messing about with it's internal variables.

EDIT:

The most obvious solution would seem to be to stop the connection from being static.  You client code might then look something like this:

```
try{
    // use using block around connection, calls dispose automatically when
    // block ends...
    using(var connectionWrapper = new Connexion_D()) {
        var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();        
        // do CRUD
    }
}
catch{
    // catching Error, avoid yellow page aspx
    // Really you should probably be doing something with the exception (logging?)
    // particularly since you go to the effort of throwing it from your Connection_D
    // class.
}
```

With your class code looking like:

```
/* Implement IDisposable to cleanup connection */
public class Connexion_D : IDisposable 
{
    public SqlConnection conn;

    public SqlConnection GetConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            String strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxxx"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception excThrown)
        {
            conn = null;
            throw new Exception(excThrown.InnerException.Message, excThrown);
        }

        // Ouverture et restitution de la connexion en cours
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
    public Boolean IsConnected
    {
        get { return (conn != null) && (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) && (conn.State != ConnectionState.Broken); }
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        // Libération de la connexion si elle existe
        if (IsConnected) { 
            conn.Close();
            conn = null;
        }
    }

    // Implement IDisposable.
    // Do not make this method virtual.
    // A derived class should not be able to override this method.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Close connection
    }
}
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) for more information about implementing IDisposable.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, can you make a suggesiton ? should i use Singleton Pattern ?

Comment: @user609511: I've updated my answer with *an approach*. Singleton *may* work, but you would have to share the connection between multiple users, which may cause problems if you're updating transactionally / reconnecting etc. I think you're better off having multiple connections to maintain isolation. You may want to look at a connection pool if you end up with performance issues, but I'd worry about that if you get there.